# Як зробити зміну та коли нажимав на якусь кнопку то до цієї зміної додавались бали в html

Tags: javascript, html, button

[image: Ще я б хотів , щоб вона стояла тут . Knopka 2. Це моя кнопка прошу допоможіть бо вже 3 години мучаюсь]
Ще я б хотів , щоб вона стояла тут . Knopka 2. Це моя кнопка прошу допоможіть бо вже 3 години мучаюсь

Comment: <button onclick="location.href='yaderka.html'">Knopka 2</button> це я так прописав кнопку чомусь вона туда не вставилась

Comment: Это SO на русском. Переведите вопрос на русский язык и добавьте в него ваш js код с html разметкой и css стилями(все, что имеет отношение к вопросу).