# Для моего сайта нужно создать переменную на js

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, button, change

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы хотел, чтобы баллы были в левом верном углу там где стрелочка. Вот моя кнопка`<button onclick="location.href='yaderka.html'">Knopka 2</button>`.
Также когда я буду нажимать на какую-нибудь кнопку то мне дадут баллы.

Comment: Вопросы [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1574137/) остались преждними. Покажите разметку html и js код, которым пытались это сделать + css стили

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.